# Контент на всю ширину экрана в адаптивной версии

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день, уважаемые специалисты. Я в ступоре, ибо не могу понять как работает адаптивность на моем сайте.

**Итак, что я делаю:**

В хедере есть следующее:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

В медиа-запросах прописал такое:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}

#wrapper {
     width: 98%;
}

#content {
float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

}
```

Т.е. я скрываю сайдбар на маленьких мониторах, а ширину основного контейнера и ширину контента делаю на весь экран. Чтобы было удобно пользователю читать сам контент.

**В чем же проблема?**

Проблема заключается в том, что  при таком раскладе все работает как надо, а сам контент растянут на 100%, но его плохо видно, т.е. для того, чтобы его посмотреть нужно увеличивать вручную на телефоне.

Вот как выглядит и как хотелось бы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что это не совсем адаптив и не претендую, просто хоть немного сделать удобнее сайт для пользователей хочу.

Понимаю, что решение на поверхности, но не вижу его. Спасите!

Comment: Почитаете, на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/) есть отличная статья. Я все сайты делаю по этому принципу,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, отвечаю сам на свой вопрос. Я перелопатил весь код и в одном из файлов нашел ужасающий момент...

```
    html {

    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Получается вся проблема была в том, что это правило тянуло сайт до 1000 пикселей, независимо от моих желаний. Хотя я и пытался выставить обнуление ширины для всех элементов.

Сейчас все стало отлично. Поправить пару моментов и будет лайт-пример мобильной версии. Всем спасибо за внимание, читайте свой код! =)

Comment: На будущее, не надо лопатить весь код, просто откройте веб-инспектор в Хроме, там есть закладка computed style, где показана ширина всех элементов. Начните с `<html>`, `<body>` и далее по порядку - если у них задана фиксированная ширина, это будет сразу заметно при ресайзе. Как только найдете фиксированный элемент - правьте его свойства налету. А потом уже в коде копайтесь =)

Comment: Спасибо, я веб-инспектор использую, но просто не ожидал увидеть в html теге какие-то свойства.

Answer (score 2):

> ...понять как работает адаптивность на моем сайте.

Их нет там :)

[Почитайте.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport)

Варианта три:

- оставить только `width=device-width`,
- переделывать верстку,
- мобильный вариант сайта.

UPD: *ответ на комментарий*

В верстке Вашего сайта основные элементы интерфейса "прибиты" намертво, то есть шаблон для сайта создавался для определенного мин. разрешения экрана по горизонтали (у "пациента" 980 или 1000px).

И при включении `initial-scale=1` (см. ссылку), часть содержимого выходит за пределы экрана (меньшего 1000px), появляется горизонтальный скролл.

"Другие" сайты избегают этого более **сложной** логикой верстки основанной, в том числе на процентном соотношении размеров элементов к размеру экрана.

Принимаемые выше меры недостаточны для появления "адаптации для просмотра на разных устройствах" (c). Соответственно, смотрите варианты выше (забыл и добавил про мобильный вариант).

Comment: width=device-width даже если просто остается - ничего не меняется. Что увеличивать то? У гугла говорят поставить контейнерам 100% ширину. Поставил, но... такая же ситуация

Comment: Увеличивать- это ручками по экрану, как у вас сейчас. Гугл советует initial-scale=1 .

Comment: Хорошо, как же тогда на других сайтах это работает?) в чем разница - не могу уловить, помогите!

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Ну так я для меньших экранов делаю ширину резиновой, почему же намертво?) Если и было намертво - переопределил же

Comment: Добавьте мета тег и попробуйте уместить хотя бы <body> в окно браузера при меньших размерах, а внесенные стили @media пока уберите